# Why does my Upstart job work with sudo but not with setuid?

Tags: sudo, upstart

I have an Upstart job for a Node.js application, and I want to make it run Node as the `node` user rather than `root`. When I use `setuid` in the job config, whenever I try to start the job, it says `my-app stop/waiting`. However, if I omit `setuid` but use `exec` with `sudo`, it works as I expect.

I have created `node` as a system user. As far as I know, all of the relevant files and directories are accessible by that user. The version of Upstart I am using is 1.12.1.

Config with `setuid`:

```
script
  setuid node
  chdir /var/app/my-app
  exec nodejs server.js
end script
```

versus the config with `sudo`:

```
script
  chdir /var/app/my-app
  exec sudo -u node nodejs server.js
end script
```

What differences are there between Upstart's `setuid` behavior and `sudo` behavior that would make one fail and the other succeed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `setuid` stanza should not be in `script` block, it's global. This is probably the reason your job fails for.

Note that using `setuid` will make **all** job phases run as the user specified and there's no way to change it. If you want to run only a daemon as a different user, avoid `sudo` and go with `start-stop-daemon` instead. This is especially important with forking daemons. Check Ubuntu's [Upstart Cookbook](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/), chapter 11.43.2 for details.

Comment: Reading now, thanks. For convenience, deep link to the section you mentioned: http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#run-a-job-as-a-different-user

Comment: Moving `setuid` outside the `script` block fixed it!